# SSRS 2008: How to count employees on each year

Tags: ssrs-2008, fetch

I have a problem where I need to count the number of employees and group on selected years. The years comes from Parameters.

E.g. if i via parameters select 2010-2013, I want to count the number of employees on Dec. 31 on those selected years. The problem is that I am limited to using Fecth from CRM 2013.

On the employees there is employment date and end date but I can’t group on this because it doesn’t tell me how many employees there are on a certain selected year. I also need to make different charts on number of employees and grouping on year.

It's not difficult to use an IIF and calculate the number of employees and put into a specific cell, but I need it to be dynamically.

EDIT: Some more thoughts...
If I use a multivalued parameter and set the available values to the years 2010-12-31…2013-12-31 and on each year I have a selection where I calculate the number of employees. Then I only need to be able to group on this multivalued parameter. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I guest that for your task if you have employee which has end date for example 2011-06-04 than he should be included in report to 2011 year. If I'm right that you need SQL expression like this one:

```
With Employee AS
(
SELECT 'employee1' as Name, '2010-02-01' as StartDate, '2012-04-01' as EndDate UNION ALL
SELECT 'employee2' as Name, '2010-02-01' as StartDate, '2011-04-01' as EndDate UNION ALL
SELECT 'employee3' as Name, '2010-02-01' as StartDate, '2011-04-01' as EndDate UNION ALL
SELECT 'employee4' as Name, '2011-02-01' as StartDate, '2012-04-01' as EndDate UNION ALL
SELECT 'employee5' as Name, '2011-02-01' as StartDate, '2012-04-01' as EndDate UNION ALL
SELECT 'employee6' as Name, '2011-02-01' as StartDate, '2012-04-01' as EndDate UNION ALL
SELECT 'employee7' as Name, '2011-02-01' as StartDate, '2012-04-01' as EndDate UNION ALL
SELECT 'employee8' as Name, '2012-02-01' as StartDate, '2012-04-01' as EndDate UNION ALL
SELECT 'employee9' as Name, '2012-02-01' as StartDate, '2012-04-01' as EndDate
) 
SELECT Employee2.Name AS EmployeeName, YEAR(Employee.StartDate) AS EmployeeWorkedYear
FROM Employee
JOIN Employee as Employee2 ON YEAR(Employee2.EndDate) >= YEAR(Employee.StartDate) AND YEAR(Employee2.StartDate) <= YEAR(Employee.StartDate)
GROUP BY YEAR(Employee.StartDate), Employee2.Name
```

It will show employee name and year in which he worked. Then you should create dataset with such expression (stored procedure) and group by second column (year) and create grouping table, charts etc.

Comment: Sadly i'm limited to only use Fetch.

Comment: I missed that you mention about Fetch CRM, I didn't work with it, but quick reviewing shows that you can use my query and in similar way with fetch synatx create the same, it supports links of ontities based on condition (I guest that it is similar to Join).